# Good documentation on starting bitcoind and bitcoin-cli after building them on Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: bitcoind

I have been following Antonopoulos book but it seems to be outdated.

I am having elementary problems. Which command to run when, after I build bitcoind and bitcoin-cli. How am I to get blockchain to start downloading?

Start with the infamous bitcoin.conf which doesn't exist and nobody knows exactly how it should come into existence.

> :~/.bitcoin$ bitcoind -datadir=/mnt/d/blockchain -txindex=1 -daemon
>   Bitcoin server starting

Ok, I assume it is now doing something, like downloading blocks.

But:

```
~/bitcoin$ bitcoin-cli -datadir=/mnt/d/blockchain -getinfo
{
  "version": 170100,
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "walletversion": null,
  "balance": null,
  "blocks": 0,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "connections": 0,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "testnet": false,
  "keypoololdest": null,
  "keypoolsize": null,
  "paytxfee": null,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "warnings": ""
}
```

implies that nothing is going on. Nothing is being downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Start with the infamous bitcoin.conf which doesn't exist and nobody knows exactly how it should come into existence.

Well, I know.

It should come into existence by you creating it with a text editor in your `datadir` directory, if you wish to do so.  It's completely optional.  If there are command line options you want to use every time without having to specify them (such as `-txindex=1`), you can put them into `bitcoin.conf`.  If you're happy continuing to give them on the command line, then there is no need for `bitcoin.conf` to exist at all.

And now you know too.

---

As for your other issue, if you use `getblockchaininfo` instead of `getinfo`, you'll get more detailed information.  Current versions of Bitcoin Core try to download block headers before getting the blocks themselves.  You'll see a `headers` field in `getblockchaininfo` which perhaps will be increasing.

Otherwise, any and all diagnostic information would be in a file called `debug.log` in your `datadir` directory.  Look at that file.  If it isn't self-explanatory, then you can post the last several lines of it in a question here, or to your other favorite Bitcoin support forum.

Comment: I guess https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/14057 is not yet in 0.17.1.